# fedora can't find mysql service

Tags: fedora, mysql

I have a VPS running Fedora 16 (upgraded from 15).
Mysql was installed and working until recently.

Now I can't get the mysql service started.

when I try

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld start
```

I get the error

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld: No such file or directory
```

I have uninstalled and installed mysql several times

```
yum install mysql mysql-server
```

but the service still isn't available

Answer (score 2):

MySQL in Fedora no longer has a SysV initscript; you should be using the `service` command to control it instead:

```
service mysqld start
```

Comment: doing a service mysqld start I get the following error: 
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Failed to connect to socket /org/freedesktop/systemd1/private: Connection refused

Comment: You're running it as root, correct?